# Memory efficent way of subclassing

Tags: java, android

It's tricky trying to come up with a meaningful question title for this. I'll explain exactly what I'm trying to do.

I have created an Android graphics library that builds a potentially large list of `Path` objects. I now have a need to attach some additional data to each `Path`. To do this, I have simply subclassed `Path` (call it `PathSubclass`) to provide the additional extended data fields. In general use cases, only very few of those `Path` objects will actually have extra data set on them. For example, there could be an `ArrayList` of several thousand `Path`s, but only a handful have additional data. As I develop the library, it is possible that the amount of extra data I want to attach to each `Path` will grow considerably. I appreciate this may be premature optimisation, but I am concerned that it is not efficient to subclass an object to contain some additional data when that additional data is very rarely populated and considerably large collections of that object are used.

What I thought of doing was perhaps having an `ExtendedPathData` class, separate from my `Path` subclass. Therefore each `Path` subclass is only bloated a little by the need for a `mExtendedData` member, which in many cases will be `null`, except for those very few `Path` objects that require the additional data. I suppose this is similar to how one would usually attach additional data to a `View`, using the `setTag()` method.

Is there any other approach I should consider, that is better for any reason?

Comment: Note that even a `null` variable still uses memory (4 bytes on a 32 bit system).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use composition instead of inheritance.

**Idea 1**

A `PathData` class might contain a reference to a `Path` and a `ExtendedPathData`:

```
// encapsulate properly in your code, this is
// just a short sample
class PathData {
  public Path path;
  public ExtendedPathData data;
}
```

This enables you to set the `data` member to `null`. Each `PathData` instance has a size of constantly two references. When the number of members in `ExtendedPathData` grows, the actual memory consumption grows only for `PathData` instances that have a non-null `data`.

**Idea 2**

You could shave off one more reference by using an interface with two implementations:

```
interface PathData {
  Path path();
  ExtendedPathData data();
}

final class NullPathData implements PathData {
  Path path;
  public Path path() { return path; }
  public ExtendedPathData data() { return null; }
}

final class ExtendedPathData implements PathData {
  Path path;
  ExtendedPathData data;
  public Path path() { return path; }
  public ExtendedPathData data() { return data; }
}
```

It's up to you to decide whether having two implementations is really worth the code, as you need a factory method here to decide what implementation to use. It's *one* 4-byte-reference per instance...

**Further stuff**

If `ExtendedPathData` is *immutable* and *many equal instances* may exist, you could also pool them by exposing a *static factory method that uses an instance pool* instead of a public constructor.

In case you've got [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](http://www.amazon.de/Effective-Java-Programming-Language-Series/dp/0321356683), here are further references explaining the tips in detail (in a more general context):

- Item 1 Consider static factory methods instead of constructors
- Item 16 Favor composition over inheritance

Comment: Many thanks for your answer - it's much appreciated. There are some great points raised here. I'll need a bit of time today before I get round to trying out ideas and accepting an answer. Regarding the Effective Java book, I admit it really is about time I obtained it.

Comment: @Trevor You're welcome. As a side note: I stumbled across a question which is a loosely related but quite good example of what you're trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197890/when-should-i-use-a-separate-class-to-represent-an-empty-container. Scala's `EmptyStack` class does save the memory for head and tail, whereas `NonEmptyStack` obviously needs it.

Answer (score 2):

Isnt it the whole point of inheritance that it is possible to store a subclass of `Path` in the below container?

```
ArrayList<Path> pathList;

pathList.add(new Path());
pathList.add(new PathPlusPlus());
```

Or am I not understanding the problem?

To do away with the ugly `isinstanceof` calls, as @assylias suggests, you can add a getter to your baseclass which returns the extended data. In the base class itself it would return `null`, and in subclasses it would return the relevant data.

Comment: This is an approach I considered, but wouldn't this mean I would have to test using `instanceof`? (The purpose of extending the class is to attach additional data, rather than modifying functionality of existing methods.)

Comment: @Trevor ideally, if you are able to, all most of it, atleast the performance intensive stuff, should work through overridden functions, otherwise yes there is an additional cost. Ofcourse just checking `null` is also a cost, smaller but is not clear how much smaller

Comment: @Trevor indeed memory wise, the null option might end up worse, since now every entry is larger by a reference.

Comment: @Trevor your could have a `getExtendedData()` method in `Path` that return null and override it in `SubPath` to return what you need.

Comment: @assylias yup just what I was gonna suggest!

Comment: Awesome - very good point. Thanks ever so for these ideas - I'm glad I asked the question now, as I've learnt something from all answers. I'll accept one later when I've spent some time on the code.