# When should I use a separate class to represent an empty container?

Tags: oop, containers

I have recently been going through the book "Scala by Example" in which the author creates an abstract class to represent a set of ints "IntSet" with two subclasses (EmptySet and NonEmptySet) as follows:

```
abstract class Stack[A] { 
  def push(x: A): Stack[A] = new NonEmptyStack[A](x, this)
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  def top: A
  def pop: Stack[A]
}

class EmptyStack[A] extends Stack[A] {
  def isEmpty = true 
  def top = error("EmptyStack.top")
  def pop = error("EmptyStack.pop")
}

class NonEmptyStack[A](elem: A, rest: Stack[A]) extends Stack[A] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def top = elem
  def pop = rest
}
```

My question is this: How useful is this paradigm of representing an empty container as its own class instead of creating one concrete class to handle both the empty and non-empty cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each *implementation is simpler and more readable* as the is-empty-check does not have to be done in the implementation. This leads to better code metric values (like cyclomatic complexity) too.

Moreover, It makes the implementations *slightly faster* in general, since the distinction between empty and non-empty does not have to be done at runtime. As far as I know, Scala's `Set` applies this technique and implements different types of sets (used depending on their size) to optimize performance.

Obviously this works for immutable data structures only.